# Let $X$ be a set all of whose elements are finite sets. Prove there is a set of all the elements of $X$ with an *even* number of elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

As the title says, I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Suppose $X$ is a set all of whose elements are finite sets. Prove that there is a set $Y$ consisting of all the elements of $X$ that have an *even* number of elements.

I'm working in ZF, and assuming only the Empty Set Axiom, the Axioms of Extensionality, Pairs, Unions and the Comprehension Scheme.

The question specifies I can't use the Power Set Axiom, but I *have* separately proven that in the case where $X$ is a ***finite*** set then there is a set which is its powerset, and so *can* use this fact.

I haven't really come up with any ideas of where to go, so would appreciate any help you could offer.

Comment: Basically, use comprehension, and find a way to describe a set with an even number of elements, right? That's what comprehension is for, after all: making sure that describable subsets are indeed subsets (for a very particular meaning of "describable").